# What is the fairness number in OpenScale dashboard if I have monitored more than one attribute?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-openscale

If I am monitoring more than one attributes (e.g Sex and Age), how is the fairness number on the dashboard computed? Does the fairness score only correspond to the attributes that have bias?

Answer (score 0):

When there are more than one fairness attribute, OpenScale computes the fairness for each of the fairness attributes independently.  This implies that we generate a fairness score for each fairness attribute and we report both of them in the GUI.  The user can drill down to look at the computed fairness for each of the fairness attributes and understand the behaviour of the model. This will include things such as what is the percentage of favourable outcome for the monitored and reference groups for each fairness attributes.  Thus OpenScale provides a complete picture of the model behaviour with respect to each of the fairness attributes.

-Manish

Answer (score 0):

The number that appears on the dashboard is the lowest fairness score for the monitored features. For example, if AGE has a fairness score of 50% and SEX has a fairness score of 70% then the fairness score presented on the dashboard would be 50%. The number represents the worst fairness score identified for any of the features monitored for fairness.